# Subsetting and Ordering in R

Tags: r

I have a random created dataframe named `a`:

```
  group marks  upd
1     a     2   up
2     b     3   up
3     a     4 down
4     b     5   up
5     a     6 down
6     c     7   up
7     a     8 down
```

I wanted to subset it with only `group='a'` and marks in decreasing order of `a`. I used this query but the marks are not arranged in decreasing order. What is the error in my code?

Here is my code and output:

```
> a[a$group=="a" & a$marks[order(a$marks,decreasing=T)],]
  group marks  upd
1     a     2   up
3     a     4 down
5     a     6 down
7     a     8 down

Warning message:
In a$group == "a" & order(a$marks, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Could you please give some sample data, IM not clear on what your data looks like.

Comment: I added the table here but it just came in one line.. I dont know how to get that in a table.. :(

Comment: Is it okay if I can suggest an alternate solution (a simpler and a nice looking one)?

Comment: @Dawny: Sure...

Comment: Never mind. Luke has included it in the answer. Use `dplyr` when manipulating data. It is much simpler and looks more elegant :)

Comment: isn't this a question about R and thus should it be on SO instead? http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic -> "If your question is not specifically on-topic for Data Science Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. "

Answer (score 2):

`a$group=="a"` gives

```
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

and `a$marks[order(a$marks,decreasing=T)]` gives

```
# [1] 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

Combining those to using a logical and (`&`) does not make much sense here. `TRUE & 8` is `TRUE` - the subsetting may accidentally work. But you want `order` to look at your subset only, not at all rows in `a`.

Try for instance

```
newa <- a[a$group=="a", ] 
newa[order(newa$marks, decreasing = TRUE), ]
#   group marks  upd
# 7     a     8 down
# 5     a     6 down
# 3     a     4 down
# 1     a     2   up
```

or, more convenient and readable:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% filter(group=="a") %>% arrange(desc(marks))
```

Comment: That was a good explanation. thank you so much. It solved my problem. And one more ques: if I just need top three marks from this output, what would the code be?

Comment: I tried to put a function here:                                                                                                               groups=unique(a$group) 
check=function(x)
{
  subdata=a[a$group==x,]
  data=subdata[order(subdata$marks,decreasing=TRUE)[1:3],]
  data
}
this was my ouput-
check(groups)       
  group marks upd
6     c     7  up
2     b     3  up
1     a     2  up   . Here, it just gave top 1 record of each group. But I wanted output to display all the top 3 records of marks of each group.

Comment: E.g. `a <- a[order(a$group, -a$marks), ];do.call(rbind, lapply(split(a, a$group), head, 3))` or `a %>% arrange(group, desc(marks)) %>% group_by(group) %>% slice(1:3)`

Answer (score 1):

without Dplyr, you could use

```
b<- a[a$group=="a",]       
c<- b[b$marks[order(b$marks,decreasing=T),]
```

this because you are referring to the order of $b$ inherited from a, and you can not use the ranking of the items of the list a to indicate where the rows of b should go.

If you need the first three items in there, take

```
head(c,3)
```

Comment: _because you are referring to the order of $b$, not of $a$_  <-- Wrong. She wants the order of _a_

Comment: b has only a subset of the rows of a, so it is shorter. Therefore the sort order needs to be as long as b, not as long as a. that is what I meant. I updated the answer to clarify. By the way, sorting is a heavy process, so t is better to sort the shorter vector rather than the longer one, if the datasets is large.